# Need to pull by date, that a value appears from different tables

Tags: union-all

I have tried unions, joins, distinct and minimum functions with some success, but still slightly off.
Example of the tables are below

```
ID      date
1            01-02-2020
2            02-02-2020
3            04-06-2020
4            01-03-2019

ID      date
1            01-03-2018
2            07-02-2019
3            10-02-2020
4            09-02-2020
```

What I want is

```
ID  date
1        01-02-2020
2        01-03-2019
3        01-03-2018
4        07-02-2019
5        10-02-2020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not pretty

But a Full OUT JOIN which MySQL doesn't have, of  both tables did the trick

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1 (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `Value_ID` INTEGER,
>   `date` VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tab1
>   (`ID`, `Value_ID`, `date`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', '01-02-2020'),
>   ('2', '2', '02-02-2020'),
>   ('3', '3', '04-06-2020'),
>   ('4', '2', '01-03-2019');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab2 (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `Value_ID` INTEGER,
>   `date` VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tab2
>   (`ID`, `Value_ID`, `date`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '3', '01-03-2018'),
>   ('2', '4', '07-02-2019'),
>   ('3', '5', '10-02-2020'),
>   ('4', '4', '09-02-2020');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT COALESCE(t2.`Value_ID`,t1.`Value_ID`) as `Value_ID`,IF (IFNULL(t1.`date`,'31-12-9999') <= t2.`date`,t1.`date`,t2.`date`)
> FROM (SELECT `Value_ID`, MIN(`date`) as `date` FROM tab1 GROUP BY `Value_ID`) t1 
> right JOIN (SELECT `Value_ID`, MIN(`date`) as `date` FROM tab2 GROUP BY `Value_ID`) t2 
> ON t1.`Value_ID` = t2.`Value_ID`
> UNION
> SELECT COALESCE(t1.`Value_ID`,t2.`Value_ID`),IF (t1.`date` <= IFNULL(t2.`date`,'31-12-9999'),t1.`date`,t2.`date`)
> FROM (SELECT `Value_ID`, MIN(`date`) as `date` FROM tab1 GROUP BY `Value_ID`) t1 
> LEFT JOIN (SELECT `Value_ID`, MIN(`date`) as `date` FROM tab2 GROUP BY `Value_ID`) t2 
> ON t1.`Value_ID` = t2.`Value_ID`
>
> ORDER BY `Value_ID`
> ```
>
> ```
> Value_ID | IF (IFNULL(t1.`date`,'31-12-9999') <= t2.`date`,t1.`date`,t2.`date`)
> -------: | :-------------------------------------------------------------------
>        1 | 01-02-2020                                                          
>        2 | 01-03-2019                                                          
>        3 | 01-03-2018                                                          
>        4 | 07-02-2019                                                          
>        5 | 10-02-2020
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3698a7353c3d5e0500b76c3c868adbdf)*

You can use Window functions

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (
  `ID` INTEGER,
  `Value_ID` INTEGER,
  `date` VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO tab1
  (`ID`, `Value_ID`, `date`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '01-02-2020'),
  ('2', '2', '02-02-2020'),
  ('3', '3', '04-06-2020'),
  ('4', '2', '01-03-2019');
  CREATE TABLE tab2 (
  `ID` INTEGER,
  `Value_ID` INTEGER,
  `date` VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO tab2
  (`ID`, `Value_ID`, `date`)
VALUES
  ('1', '3', '01-03-2018'),
  ('2', '4', '07-02-2019'),
  ('3', '5', '10-02-2020'),
  ('4', '4', '09-02-2020');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    `Value_ID`, `date`
FROM
(SELECT
`Value_ID`, `date`
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `Value_ID` ORDER BY `date` ASC) rn
FROM
(SELECT `Value_ID`, MIN(`date`) as `date` FROM tab1 GROUP BY `Value_ID`
UNION
SELECT `Value_ID`, MIN(`date`) as `date` FROM tab2 GROUP BY `Value_ID`) t1
 ) t3
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

| Value_ID | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-02-2020 |
| 2 | 01-03-2019 |
| 3 | 01-03-2018 |
| 4 | 07-02-2019 |
| 5 | 10-02-2020 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/exfkgCJpH9X4ped4S2PGpj/2)

Comment: I appreciate your! And that looks like it would work.

Comment: I apologize if this is rude to ask but is there any simpler way to do that? I only ask because this answer is going to be reviewed by a peer and if I sent them this it would be fairly obvious it was not my work. But again I appreciate your help!

Comment: i added another Version